# IV&V relevant Quality metrics

Tags: manual-testing, metrics, quality-assessment

We are in the IV&V phase of a web application, which is being developed and tested by a completely separate team. So, the client for which we are working has two vendors one which is developing and testing the software and other is **‘We’** the IV&V team.

As a part of this team we are not concerned about their internal practices, daily activities, team composition and their trackers for task and issues. What we are concerned about the Quality and Delivery of the product, Code Review, Test Plan review, Test Cases review, Process being followed by them should be as per Industry standards & guidelines and responsible for pre-UAT (i.e. we will execute sampled test cases/Validate the flow of the application) *(this all detail might be required for phrasing context of my question)*

We used to have all of the following and few other metrics, when I was part of the actual testing team

1. Defect Density
2. Defect Leakage
3. Defect Removal Efficiency
4. Test Cases Passed/Failed
5. Test case execution efficiency

Now my questions are:-

1. Are these metrics relevant for me when I am doing IV&V of a project?
2. Do I need any quality metrics from their side?
3. If answer of 2 is Yes, What are other metrics, which I should ask them to provide from IV&V point of view both for Functional and Non-Functional requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are these metrics relevant for me when I am doing IV&V of a project?

The point of [IV&V](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/24836/independent-verification-and-validation--iv&v) is to have someone look at your project with a fresh pair of eyes and report anything that doesn't match the outlined requirements. This 3rd party wont need anything besides the list of requirements, really. Just think, do they care if your previous tests are passing and failing? Nope.

> Do I need any quality metrics from their side?

You will probably only receive a list of "issues" found while they manually tested. You can derive some metrics from this if you wish, but what benefit is there? Just fix the issues and your dev/qa team can write up the new test cases for things they didn't think of for future regressions.